# Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes in SignalR-Client-Swift

Tags: ios, swift, real-time, guid, signalr.client

I am new to iOS. I am working on Swift SignalR using SignalR-Client-Swift. Initially it was working fine but now it is returning below error while subscribing channels.

- Connection opens successfully
- Error on invoke callback

> *hubInvocationError(message: "An unexpected error occurred invoking 'Subscribe' on the server. FormatException: Guid should contain 32
> digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).")

Go through my code below.

```
self.hubConnection.invoke(method: "Subscribe", connectionID, [userID+"_plan", userID+"_notification", userID+"_messaging", userID+"_setting", userID+"_refresh", "4d06546f-f990-40bc-aefe-08b1eb5f7319_messaging"]) { error in
    print("SignalR Workitem Subscribe Error :", error ?? "nil")
}
```

In above code,  is GUID appending with underscored strings(Channels/Subscription), it was working fine initially, but now it stopped. I have google a lot, but couldn't fix this error.

Gone through these links:

https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/274651/guid-should-contain-32-digits-with-4-dashes-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx

https://github.com/moozzyk/SignalR-Client-Swift/commits/master/Examples/HubSamplePhone/ViewController.swift

https://github.com/moozzyk/SignalR-Client-Swift/issues

Comment: The error description seems pretty obvious. The GUID has been manipulated by appending a string. `_messaging` to be precise. Why?

Comment: Because we need to subscribe at those channels, initially it was working fine. Error is happening from few days.